# Showing data on Bar graph using Linq and Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Wanted help with the code.
I want to show my data on a bar graph which i am able to do but i wanted to do it more professionally and with group by in linq but i was not able to do so.
I am using Genetella Admin Layout template for graphs.
My code in the controller section is as below

```
public ActionResult Home()
        {
            int jan = 0,feb = 0,mar = 0,apr = 0,may = 0,jun = 0,jul = 0 ,aug = 0 ,sep = 0,oct = 0 ,nov = 0,dec = 0;
            ViewData["Freetrialcompanies"] = admin.getAllCompanies();
            List<string> month = new List<string>();
            foreach ( var cmpMonth in ViewData["Freetrialcompanies"] as IEnumerable<IntuitiveCrm.ViewModels.CompanyMasterViewModel>)
            {
                var mth = DateTimeOffset.Parse((cmpMonth.CreatedDate).ToString()).ToString("MMMM");
                month.Add(mth);
                switch (mth)
                {
                    case "January":
                        jan = jan + 1;
                        var Janmth = jan;
                        if(Janmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["jan"] = Janmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["jan"] = 0;
                        }

                    break;

                    case "February":
                        feb = feb + 1;
                        var Febmth = feb;
                        if (Febmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["feb"] = Febmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["feb"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "March":
                         mar = mar + 1;
                        var Marmth = mar;
                        if (Marmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["mar"] = Marmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["mar"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "April":
                        apr = apr + 1;
                        var Aprmth = apr;
                        if (Aprmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["apr"] = Aprmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["apr"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "May":
                        may = may + 1;
                        var Maymth = may;
                        if (Maymth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["may"] = Maymth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["may"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "June":
                        jun = jun + 1;
                        var Junmth = jun;
                        if (Junmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["jun"] = Junmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["jun"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "July":
                        jul = jul + 1;
                        var Julmth = jul;
                        if (Julmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["jul"] = Julmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["jul"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "August":
                        aug = aug + 1;
                        var Augmth = aug;
                        if (Augmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["aug"] = Augmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["aug"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "September":
                        sep = sep + 1;
                        var Sepmth = sep;
                        if (Sepmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["sep"] = Sepmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["sep"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "October":
                        oct = oct + 1;
                        var Octmth = oct;
                        if (Octmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["oct"] = Octmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["oct"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "November":
                        nov = nov + 1;
                        var Novmth = nov;
                        if (Novmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["nov"] = Novmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["nov"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "December":
                        dec = dec + 1;
                        var Decmth = dec;
                        if (Decmth != 0)
                        {
                            ViewData["dec"] = Decmth;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewData["dec"] = 0;
                        }
                        break;

                }

            }
            ViewData["Mnth"] = month;
            return View();
        }
```

In this i am getting the month name from created date which is stored in datetimeoffset format in "mth" and the segregating it for getting the count.

My cs file code is as below for admin.getAllCompanies();

```
public List<CompanyMasterViewModel> getAllCompanies()
        {
            var taskData = (from t in Comp.GetAll()
                            join p in plan.GetAll()
                            on t.PlanId equals p.PlanId
                            join f in freeTrial.GetAll()
                            on t.CompanyId equals f.CompanyId
                            where t.Status == 1
                            select new CompanyMasterViewModel
                            {
                                CompanyName = t.CompanyName,
                                PlanName = p.PlanName,
                                Email = t.Email,
                                CreatedDate = f.CreatedDate,
                                EndDate = f.EndDate,
                                Status = t.Status,
                            }).ToList<CompanyMasterViewModel>();
            return taskData;
        }
```

With this i am generating the following bar graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUiUI.png)

Can any one help me better this code and how to write linq query so that i get createddate(it is stored in datetimeoffset) in orderby with only month.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine several different solutions but you may try the following. I don't know if you use the `getAllCompanies()` method on more places but I would assume that it's the case so I'm not going to change this method. You can add another method in your business layer that would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CompanyCountView> companyCountByMonth()
{
    List<CompanyMasterViewModel> companies = this.getAllCompanies();
    ILookup<int, Company> byMonths = companies.ToLookup(key => key.CreatedDate.Month);

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        yield return new CompanyCountView
        {
            Date = new DateTime(2016, i, 1),
            Count = months[i].Count()
        };
    }
}
```

The CompanyCountView class is a new view model I created to keep things neat:

```
public class CompanyCountView
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

in the Controller, you'll just call this function. I recommend to use view models in views and limit using the ViewData to minimum. It's better for the maintenance.

```
public ActionResult Home() 
{
    IEnumerable<CompanyCountView> model = admin.companyCountByMonth();
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view where you need to display the 3-letter abbreviation. Just use this:

```
@item.Date.ToString("MMM")
```

I'm not sure how you handle years. If the chart is supposed to display months within one year or months from all entries - some kind of statistics. If it's just from a particular year, just replace my hardcoded value "2016" with the year you need.

If it's the other case and you don't want to create an instance of DateTime type just to store a month, or you need to take localization into consideration. Then you can use slightly different approach. You just need to create enumeration

```
public enum Months {
    Jan = 1,
    Feb = 2,
    Mar = 3

    // etc.
}
```

and update the model view `CompanyCountview`:

```
public class CompanyCountView
{
    public Months Date { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and the `companyCountByMonth()` function:

```
public IEnumerable<CompanyCountView> companyCountByMonth()
{
    List<CompanyMasterViewModel> companies = this.getAllCompanies();
    ILookup<int, Company> byMonths = companies.ToLookup(key => key.CreatedDate.Month);

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        yield return new CompanyCountView
        {
            Date = (Months)i,
            Count = months[i].Count()
        };
    }
}
```

The last note is about the `getAllCompanies()` function. If this function was created merely for this particular view, I would consider to perform `group by` on the query before you load everything to memory. But in that case my solution would have to be adjusted :) I just hope you get a gist how it can be simplified.